# What is the best method for numerical integration of this one

Tags: numerical-integration

I have an integral as follows $$\int_0^\infty r^k \psi(r) dr \tag{1}$$ where $$\psi=e^{-ar-br^2-cr^3-dr^4}\tag{2}$$ I tried `NIntegrate` It woks for some values but after a few cycles of a loop it returns the following error

> NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand E^(-r-7.58165 r^2-2.52722
>   r^3+2.25446 r^4) has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity
>   for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,17545.1}}.

I replaced $\infty$ by a 150 for example but it also returns the error. I want to know is there a way to evaluate (1) using  a modified `NIntegrate` for example or I have to write a code for integration using  a user-defined algorithm, Gauss quadrature for example? And  if the latter is the case, what is the best method to do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the coefficient of the largest power of `r` is positive, then the integral diverges. The coefficient in your case is 2.25446, a positive number.

Comment: @CarlWoll  Many thanks, So what is the solution?!

Comment: Make sure the coefficient is negative?

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanka a lot, You were right, I had put an additional minus in definition of $d$, I corrected it but it's very interesting that this time it returns the error in the first cycle and again the coefficient of $r^4$ is positive! and I don't understand how!?

Comment: Then there's probably something wrong with the underlying model, you should double check it.

Comment: Now it returns `NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in r near {r} = {149.999997222185673858789457091713129277543714579223887994885444641}. NIntegrate obtained 3.48856548998427512598410480966562841427220636426313804333768449469`65.954589770191*^908629213 and 4.40964904660889007680781694994052295337293635790607012838629670891`65.954589770191*^908629211 for the integral and error estimates.`